Automatic weights won't work for figure model
Context:

I'm trying to rig a model (this is for figure drawing reference so a rough solution is fine).

The original model was a bunch of loose parts (lots of overlapping/intersecting parts, internal geometry)

this made rigging via automatic weights impossible.


What I've tried:

made a duplicate of the model and added a bunch of modifiers (geometry nodes: mesh to volume + volume to mesh, displace (?), shrinkwrap, decimate)

I applied these and was able to get a rough mesh that was one continuous skin (i.e., not loose parts).


The problem:

I tried rigging this new mesh with autoweights but could not get it to work. Lots of "melted cheese" when moving limbs

All help appreciated, TY!
Here's the blend file if necessary: https://file.io/UrWTfpuXarPA

Hello, your mesh is super high-poly, it's going to make any animation very tedious, the best idea is to create a low-poly version (retopologize)

That Blend file has already been deleted from the download site.
